# Query to find users from where?

Tags: sql, stackexchange

Based on my question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87044/query-to-find-users-from-australia), I have updated my query to take user input so it can be a generic query:

```
DECLARE @location AS nvarchar(max) = ##location:string##;
SELECT u.Id [User Link], u.Reputation, u.Location
FROM Users u
WHERE lower(u.Location) LIKE lower('%' + @location + '%')
ORDER BY 'Reputation' DESC
```

Is there something I should be doing differently, or is this good?

Comment: As d347hm4n's answer points out, we should be careful about our column types.  `Users.Location` is `NVarChar(100)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks fine, the only thing I would say is `@location` is being declared as `nvarchar(max)`. I can only assume that `u.Location` is also `nvarchar(max)`. If it isn't then set it to be the same size. nvarchar max will have a slight performance hit to it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to add a table alias when you are only dealing with a single table.

Also there's no need to worry about `LOWER` as the columns have a case insensitive collation.

Fixing the datatype issue mentioned in the comments and removing the unnecessary other stuff mentioned above you would end up with.

```
DECLARE @location AS NVARCHAR(100) = ##location:string##;

SELECT Id AS [User Link],
       Reputation,
       Location
FROM   Users
WHERE  Location LIKE '%' + @location + '%'
ORDER  BY Reputation DESC
```

One other thing to consider is if the input itself might contain any characters of special significance in the `LIKE` pattern syntax.

It is unlikely that any legitimate locations will contain characters such as `%`, `_`, `[`.

If you do want to correctly support searches for these strings you would need to either `ESCAPE` them all or just use `CHARINDEX` instead.

```
SELECT Id AS [User Link],
       Reputation,
       Location
FROM   Users
WHERE CHARINDEX(@location, Location) > 0
ORDER  BY Reputation DESC
```